# Creating a Windows service with user notification in C#?

Tags: .net, windows-services

I want to create Windows service in such a way :

-> It takes input database information ...

-> at completion of service it notifies user for completion of process.

How can I do this with Windows service in C#.Net?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking three questions:

1. How do I create a Windows Service
2. How do I open and read data from a database
3. How do I notify a user

Answers:

1. [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx)
2. If you can use .NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2005 or 2008, I would recommend [LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)
3. A Windows Service has no UI, so you would need to think about how you want to notify the user. The simplest option might be to [send them an email](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3096831).

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the clues you provided in your question, I think you should probably look at WCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

Comment: WCF is great for n-tier scenarios or disributed applications, I'm not sure how this would help this application.